# Java for loops with post-incrementation within the loop

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So I am having a difficult time understanding how to accomplish a seemingly easy task within my Java homework. Below is an excerpt for an "application" within my overall assignment. Numbers **1-3** is what is causing me the trouble but I provided the whole requirements list for context.

**Requirements-**

**1)** Assume that there are 5 students in a class.

**2)** I need to build an application that creates two arrays to store students’ names and students’ grades. The names of the arrays are name and grade respectively.

**3)** The application asks the user to enter five students’ names, students’ midterm scores, and final scores. To take care of the repeated work, the application *must* utilizes loop(s). The students’ names are stored to the name array.

**4)** The application calls (invokes) a method and the method name is "average". The method "average" has two parameters for the midterm score and the final score
of a student. The method returns the average of the scores.

**5)** The application calls (invokes) a method and the method name is function. The method “function” has two parameters: one is the average which is computed in **4)** and the other is the final score. The method returns the higher score between
two scores.

**6)** The application calls (invokes) a method and the method name is function. The
method “function” has one parameter for the highest score in **5)**. The method
returns the grade.

**7)** The grades are stored to the grade array.
**−** If the highest score is greater than 90, A will be returned.
**−** If the highest score is greater than 80, B will be returned.
**−** If the highest score is greater than 70, C will be returned.
**−** If the highest scores is less than or equal to 70, F will be returned.

**My Problem-** I cant seem to figure out how to write the loop in a way that will gather the information on the 5 students while also postincrementing the value names that will be used as elements within the array after each loop.

**Here's what I have so far-**

```
for (int q = 0; q<5; q++) {
    int w = 1;
    System.out.println("Student" + w);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the student name: ");
    String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
    String name2 = String.valueOf(name1);

    System.out.println("Enter the midterm score: ");
    double midterm = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter the final score: ");
    double finalScore = scanner.nextDouble();

    String name[] = {name2};
    double grade[] = {midterm, finalScore};
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Jeeze! Of course I would butcher the title on my first post... I meant  to say post incrementation not incrimination! Smh

Comment: You can edit it. Add missing "}" while you're at it.

Comment: Is the `grade[]` array supposed to help the midterm and final score?

Comment: Yes, I will need the grade[] array to be a concatenation of both the midterm[] and finalScore[] arrays after the loop ends and scores for both tests have been entered for all 5 students.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have to solve this using separate arrays? I'd wrap up name, grade, score in a "Student" object and iterate over a collection of them.